# Описать WebSocket client на Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket

Мне нужно подключиться к WebSocket'y и получить от него данные, как это сделать? Я даже не знаю с чего начать, пробовал искать информацию но конкретно с Kotlin нет ничего.

---

https://gist.github.com/SheptunovaAA/90b9cb9388420cd028aa5dab3d754252

Вот здесь всё описано, довольно не сложно

Comment: ?socket.io - https://stackoverflow.com/q/50894816/4794368